# Firebase Crashlytics - get stacktrace info to display during CrashlyticsListener.crashlyticsDidDetectCrashDuringPreviousExecution()

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I have Firebase Crashlytics completely operational, and I'm using the CrashlyticsListener with crashlyticsDidDetectCrashDuringPreviousExecution() method to display a pop up when the app restarts after the crash.

I can't seem to find a way to access the custom keys and/or the stacktrace from the crash to display to the end-user.  I've scoured through here and can't find anyone else wanting to do the same as me.

Can anyone please help?

```
     final CrashlyticsListener listener = new CrashlyticsListener() {
        @Override
        public void crashlyticsDidDetectCrashDuringPreviousExecution() {
            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(BaseActivity.this);
            adb.setTitle("ERROR!");

            adb.setMessage(**WOULD LIKE STACKTRACE HERE/OR SOME CUSTOM KEYS THAT WERE SET AT CRASH INIT**);

            adb.setPositiveButton("DISMISS", null);
            AlertDialog ad = adb.create();
            ad.show();              
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to get any data form the previous crash report, although what you can provide are the custom keys from the current session, assuming they are always same for a particular user.